# xml elements lost during processing with php

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I have an xml file, but the structure is not processing correctly. I am clueless regarding why this keeps happening. Is there anything I should be aware of when processing xml in PHP version 5.1.6? (I'm quite aware of the security issues via VPN and no outside access. I do not wish to upgrade right now.)

Here is the xml structure:

```
<XML>
  <actions>
    <action>
      <action_id>1</action_id>
    </action>
   <action>
     <action_id>2</action_id>
   </action>
  </actions>
  <actionreferences>
   <actionreference>
     <action_id>2</action_id>
     <reference>1</reference>
   </actionreference>
  </actionreferences>
</XML>
```

This schema can have more actions and thus more references, new actions can be based but must not be based on another action. We have no DTD, but our php code logic relies in the structure and has some safe guards in place. Most important for me, it has fine grained coded logging for each action and reference it finds.

The php script after receiving the XML file writes the actions and the references to MySQL DB server.

So the problem is, sometimes action references are missing. From the logging of the php it looks as they never reached the server. I was not able to replicate this in my lab setup, but have assured that it happened on our live system 0.4% of transactions, about 10 times.

- I rule out that the xml is generated wrong, as we manually tested our Win32 application that generates the xml to function correctly
- I rule out an xml file corruption during transit because it would lead to Errors being thrown, I cut off the xml in the actionreference area and tried again

What else am I missing, what can lead to these references not being processed once in a while?

Update Details

The xml files are generated based of a mdb access db on windows with a .net 2.0 client. We rule out issues in the generation of the xml as:

- manually started/closed it several time and did a diff on the resulting xml files, always the same as expected, has been in use on other system for 2y not experience the problem
- php script  using simple xml2array function
- xml files are gzipped and POST to a php script running on Apache 2
- we reviewed all logs of apache and of php custom log, no transfer errors in there, the client writes out a log too, no errors in there, however the client we currently use does not log the html return, it just logs the HTTP 200 OK
- the php xml is http://us4.php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php
- I cannot totally rule out the MySQL as I found some errors in the Apache error log, some mysql db errors I did not correctly catch in php
  Maybe catching all mysql errors properly will give me more insight, but they seem to be unrelated on first sight

Comment: We might need more info on this:
1. How are the XML files being generated and how have you ruled out file-generation as the problem?
2. How are the XML files being passed to the PHP parser? Might there by a transfer error?
3. Is it possible that you're seeing character encoding problems? What encoding is being used in the generation and parsing?
4. Could we see the PHP code that you're using to parse?
5. Have you confirmed that the parser is the issue and not the MySQL-write that's the problem?
Basically, just give us a more concrete walk-through of each stage and how you tested it.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you have an error in your XML:

```
<reference>1</references>
```

should be

```
<reference>1</reference>
```

(notice the "s")

Comment: That is not the issue, I corrected the typo. The real XML is far more complex and holds a lot more information in the action section, so I wrote the xml down by hand. It has been in use for month, and as said the error is not consistently reproducible.